# Django url regex not matching

Tags: regex, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am trying to implement a regex url for these examples:

> > localhost:8000/curvas?parcela=298

or

> > localhost:8000/curvas?parcela=7&fk_fecha=234

I tried implementing a similar url regex from django rest framework ([documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-url)) with the following regex path:

```
re_path(r'curvas(?P<parcela>.+)', views.CurvasFilter.as_view()),
```

And it works but it is too permisive, for example that url also match the regex:

> localhost:8000/curvas?random=298

How can I change the regex to match only the desired url params?

Comment: `parcela` is part of the *querystring*, not the *path*, hence you can not capture this with `url(..)`, `re_path(..)` or `path(..)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part after the question mark (`?`) is the [*querystring* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). It is *not* part of the path, and thus you can not capture it with `path(..)` or `re_path(..)`. It would furthermore likely not be a good idea anyway, since often the order of the parameters is random, and thus a regex that matches `?foo=4&bar=2` might have difficulty with `?bar=2&foo=4`.

The path is thus:

```
re_path(r'^curvas/$', views.CurvasFilter.as_view())
```

You can access the value for `parcela` with `self.request.GET['parcela']`. For example:

```
class CurvasFilter(ListView):
    model = Curvas

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(
            parcela=self.request.GET['parcela']
        )
```

Comment: Thanks, so I will use the following regex: r'^curvas?$' which seems more restrictive, isn't it? (it also requires to the url to have the question mark)

Comment: @David1212k: no the question mark is not part of the path either, it should be `^curvas/$` (or `^curvas$`, so without the question mark). Note that here the question mark is by the way interpreted as a regular expression quantifier ("*zero or one*").